# MediaRecorder record and transfer video

Tags: media-player, wifi-direct

i am trying to write an App that records a video on one device and sends it to another device via WiFi-Direct.

Now i already have trouble with recording the video with the MediaRecorder.
I build my app after the following Code-Example 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java
when setting a file as outputfile for the MediaRecorder the mediaRecorder.prepare() and mediarecorder.start() work, but when i call the mediaRecorder.stop() Method my app crashes. I get an error something like "mediaRecorder stop() failed  -1007" in console.
I checked suggested solutions from this question
[Android mediarecorder stop failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147563/android-mediarecorder-stop-failed/13264564)
but it did not help to solve my Problem.
I also tried some samplecode i found, to directly use `ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(skt)` and`mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());` to not having to safe the Video, and play it with MediaPlayer on the other device, but then teh mediaRecorder.prepare() already gives an exeption

thx already for any possible help i will get

*edit

after saving the video, the next problem came: transfering it.
The devices are connexted via Wifidirect and there is a shared socket.
I wanna send the video liek this:

```
public void sendFile(String filepath) {
        int len;
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        try {
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            File file = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            is.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

there si no exeption on the sending side, but how can i see if really the data of the whole file was send?
On the receiving side i tried the following:`public class SendReceive extends Thread {

```
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    public SendReceive(Socket skt) {
        socket = skt;
        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
        String path = null;
        try {
            while (inputStream.read(bytes) != -1) {
                String filename = (getFilesDir() + "/")
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
                int count;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or 4096, or more
                OutputStream out = null;
                BufferedOutputStream    bos= null;
                try {
                    File video = new File(filename);
                    File dirs = new File(video.getParent());
                    if (!dirs.exists())
                        dirs.mkdirs();
                    video.createNewFile();

                    path = video.getAbsolutePath();
                    out = new FileOutputStream(video);
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("File not found. ");
                }


                copyFile(inputStream,bos);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                //      showVideo(filename);
                byte[] namearray = path.getBytes();
                handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, counter, -1, namearray).sendToTarget();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

.
.
.

```
public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.flush();

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When doing it like this no file is created in the location of the path, but i do receive bytes from the input stream. I just want to safe the video i sent from one device on the other device and after play with MediaPlayer

greetings

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution to my Problem with recordintg the video. This entry helped me:
[capturing a video using camera2 and MediaRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777705/capturing-a-video-using-camera2-and-mediarecorder)

It seems in most samples i found one simple thing was missing:

```
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
```

...adding survaces i want a capture with, set up mediaRecorder, prepare MediaRecorder etc...

```
CaptureRequest request;
request= mPreviewBuilder.build();
 cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                   @Override
                   public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession ccs) {
                       cameraCaptureSession = ccs;
                     updatePreview();
                       getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               // UI
                               start.setText("stop");
                               isrecording = true;

                               try {
                                   cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(request,
                                           new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                                                   super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                                   super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                                               }
                                           }, null);
                               } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }

                           }
                       });
                       mMediaRecorder.start();
                   }
```

Maybethis helps anyone with a similar issue